# Consuming StackOverflow API and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, stackexchange-api

I have downloaded [TheWorldsWorstStackOverflowClone](https://stackapps.com/questions/3/the-worlds-worst-stackoverflow-clone). One of the project is called TheWorldWorsts.ApiWrapper, which basically is the core of accessing the API. There is a class called ApiProxy.cs, which has all the methods for the API call. This is good.

Now what I want to do is I am trying to collect data from this API interface and store it in a database. I know the limit to the API call is 10k per day. I.e: I want to be able to call the method in the ApiProxy class 10k times per day, done automatically. How can I do this?

The non-automatic way would be to create a dummy site where when every time I access the site it does all that process, but this not efficient. It seems that I have to write some kind of a scheduler by deploying a web service, but that is too complicated... as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx). Any other simpler methods?

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Service or Desktop App might be a better solution than a web application. You are not deploying a web service, you are consuming one using a proxy class, and this does not require you to have a web server or a web site.

You could use a web application to control and monitor progress as your service downloads data, but the actual work is long running and needs to be offloaded to another process or thread so you can tell the user whats going on.

Comment: any tutorial on how to do this? as I have no idea with windows service

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one
http://stacky.codeplex.com/
This looks what you need, though I am facing some debugging issues, but hope you can figure it out.